# Solving a recurrence by generating functions, why the subtraction in this example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

[image: Question]

I do not understand the step where 
A(x) - 1 - 2xA(x) = 0.
I am guessing that it has something to do with the powers of n being different in each summation (n vs n-1), but I do not understand how that is dealt with by simply subtracting 1.

Please explain why subtracting 1 would solve the different powers of n problem. If that is not what solves that problem, please explain why we subtract 1, and then why the different powers of n do not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $A$ is defined by $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ (note the index starts at $0$), we have
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n - a_0 x^0 = A(x) -a_0 = A(x) - 1
$$
since $a_0=1$.

Moreover, $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_{n} x^{n} = A(x)$ by a change of indices, so
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n x^n - 2x \sum_{n\geq 1} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} 
= (A(x) - 1) - 2x A(x) = A(x) - 1 - 2x A(x)
$$
as stated.